# power bi pin tile from other reports

Tags: powerbi

In our organization we have reports relevant for different departments and I need only one view, tile to bring it to our department report. The data sets is the same and I find it unproductive for us to build the report from scratch when we could use one tile from the different departments  reports. Is there any way I could do it? The pin bottom is not active and I cannot copy it in my dashboard. Are there any specific security roles that I should have? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pin your specific visualization to your live dashboard and you ned power bi pro licence.